# unable to Get GPS Location "BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted"

Tags: objective-c, gps

I am trying to get the Location "Latitude & Longitude".
The steps which I did as follow:

In CurrentLocationViewController.m:

```
@implementation CurrentLocationViewController {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
```

Then in CurrentLocationViewController.h

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface CurrentLocationViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

Back to In CurrentLocationViewController.m:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}


- (IBAction)getLocation:(id)sender {
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError %@", error);
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation !=nil) {
        self.longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        self.latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }
}
```

I put Break point on each methods, and even though, when I run the application, i got message in the Console: BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same error message, still can't fix 'BSXPCMessage' error, but about the location part, I guess you're running iOS 7 version codes on iOS 8?
If so, try this:

1. Add `[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]` or `[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]` above `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]`
2. open Info.plist, add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` into 'information property list' with a message

That's it, hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the same error message when working with AVFoundation. Images and videos. It's not specific to what you do.